# How can I compensate for the nonlinearity of the transconductance (input admittance) Vgs to Id in the Vds saturated region of linear MOSFETs?

Tags: power, mosfet, current, control

We're using a circuit similar to a standard current source application as shown [here.](https://circuitsgeek.com/tutorials/fet-current-source/)

Added: we're using the fet in a high bandwidth opamp loop measuring current via a shunt resistor.

We're driving an inductive load at bandwidths above 1MHz and high pulsed current up to the die-temperature limits of a linear MOSFET (IXTA64N10L2).

In favour of maintaining the same control loop gain for all currents from 2A to 30A, I could use some hints on how to linearize the input admittance characteristics Vgs to Id.

The FET is used in the saturated Vds region.

Are there common used ways / best practices to linearize this admittance?
And as such have the abillity to further optimally tune the performance of the control loop?

Comment: I believe you need a depletion-mode device to implement the circuit in your link.  Using an enhancement-mode MOSFET will not work.  Digikey can sort by depletion-mode:  https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors/fets-mosfets/single-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcoJwKwyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIAzJQBwAMATACwgC6RADgC5QgDKXAE4BLAHYBzEAF8ZQA

Comment: Emiel - Hi, As there are multiple schematics on the page that you linked, can you please clarify which one your circuit is similar to? I guess it's [this one](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/tran80.gif). Please confirm. (FYI that whole page (and many others) on circuitsgeek.com is an uncredited copy (hence apparent plagiarism) from the Electronics Tutorials website [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/fet-current-source.html)).

Comment: I suggest you post the full current source circuit, including the actual op-amp type used, all components in the feedback loop, and also some description (or a circuit!) that drives the input of said op-amp. The particular approach will depend somewhat on how your circuits look in detail. The "example" you've posted is not nearly enough. The simplest solution may well be not to deal with any of this: drive two complementary output currents - one into the load, another into a dummy load.

Comment: Your use of the word "bandwidth" implies analogue current control. But you also say you will operate the transistor saturated, which suggests digital on/off control. Then you suggest the voltage-controlled current source, and we're back to analogue. Is this PWM? Are you trying to control current in a linear closed loop? Are you switching on, waiting for current to rise to some threshold, then off again, waiting, and so on? What's going on?

Comment: Oh, and what's the inductance of the load, nanohenries, millihenries?

Answer (score 1):

You need a depletion-mode device to implement the circuit in your link.  JFETs are always depletion mode, but [MOSFETs can also come in depletion-mode](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Application_Note_Applications_for_Depletion_MOSFETs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624cb7f111014cd63d1a197d94).  Using an enhancement-mode MOSFET will not work in the same way. Digikey can sort by depletion-mode for MOSFETs:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors/fets-mosfets/single-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcoJwKwyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIAzJQBwAMATACwgC6RADgC5QgDKXAE4BLAHYBzEAF8ZQA

---

Another downside to the linked circuit is that the "constant" current it provides can be quite poor.  Not only does \$I_{DSS}\$ vary greatly from device to device, but there is a slope due to the series resistance of the device.  Below is a plot from a rather simple simulation which shows this error.  This is for a JFET [*NOTE: depletion MOSFETs are usually better at this*].

[image]

You can tackle all three of these problems by using a MOSFET within an opamp's feedback loop: (1) you can use an enhancement MOSFET, (2) the output is linearized with respect to the input, (3) the "constantness" of the current is quite flat and more accurate/predictable.  [This article from Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/current-output-circuit-techniques-add-versatility.html) shows a typical schematic for this approach (duplicated below).

[image]

The above is for a constant current sink, but you can make a constant current source by swapping for a P-channel MOSFET and flipping it, along with the sense resistor, upside-down.  You cannot do this with a depletion N-channel MOSFET because of its asymmetry and its intrinsic body diode (a JFET lacks this), and also nobody makes a depletion P-channel MOSFET. Anyway, an example using an opamp with enhancement P-channel can be found here in this previous question:

[Op-Amp + MOSFET = Constant Current Power Source (?)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178605)

[image]

Below is an oversimplified example showing generic input->output characteristics.  The load voltage is swept, and each discrete plot is at a different control voltage.  Since the control voltage is referenced to the power supply voltage, it's easiest for the control to be ratiometric like in the above linked question which uses a voltage divider.  If you want it to be software controlled, you'll need some extra circuitry to handle this part depending on how fine the control must be and what voltages you're going to be running at the load.

[image]

The last thing to keep in mind is how that current doesn't stay constant and begins to slope down as both the current and voltage increase.  This is something called the "compliance voltage", and is typically overlooked when dealing with current sources.  This example can't even reach the 9A or 10A points at any load voltage.  In this circuit, it's mainly a function of the \$V_{GS(th)}\$ and \$R_{DS(on)}\$ of the MOSFET. Again, you need to determine what kinds of voltages you need at your load before you can land on a final design, including if these types of circuits can even meet your requirements in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches:

1. Avoid the problem, e.g. control complementary currents.
2. Throw the inverse admittance into the feedback loop.

The approach #2 works well with at least partially digital control loops, since it's easy with those to characterize admittance at all current levels and DS voltages the circuit experiences, and then apply the inverse admittance as a feedback correction factor. A characterization observer looks at the current, DS, and GS voltages on the mosfet, and builds a 2-dimensional fitted model. A fast multiplying DAC applies the inverse of the admittance derived from the model into the control loop, stabilizing the gain. If the control loop is fully digital, the multiplying DAC is not necessary.

Another approach is to continuously measure the admittance in a purely analog fashion, by splitting the output current across two matched output devices, well thermally bonded, with a fixed small offset between their gate voltages. The control loop output has two offsets added to it, and those become the gate voltages. Since the offset is fixed, the difference between the currents is a direct measure of admittance. An inverse of that is then taken, and applied using analog multiplication in the feedback loop, to stabilize loop gain.

A basic admittance-sensing circuit looks as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5KmSG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ADM voltage - proportional to admittance, normalized to 1.0 at I1=100mA - as a function of reference total current I1:

[image]

> high pulsed current up to the die-temperature limits

Derating this at least 50% will go a long way towards usable admittance estimate that can be then used to vary the feedback gain.

The admittance monitor's gain must be shaped as necessary - if the DC offset changes slowly (does it??) and has some superimposed AC component, then the admittance monitor needs to be sensitive only around DC.

If the admittance should be measured at some other frequency than DC, the offset voltages will have to be sine waves at that frequency. The admittance output V(ADM) will have to be I-Q demodulated, the magnitude taken, and that then used as a gain adjustment signal.